# Emacs inserts EOF for "<<<"

Tags: emacs

While using emacs to edit a bash shell script (#!/bin/sh), anytime I attempt to enter "<<<", on the third bracket it places 'EOF' directly after the bracket, and places two carriage returns at the end of the line, and writes 'EOF' again, like below:

```
   resiline=$(grep -w -n "$searchstring" input/*)
   resifile=$(cut -d \: -f 1 <<<EOF $resiline)

EOF
```

Why does it do this and how do I prevent it from doing that?

Comment: Here-docs using two arrows like `<<` and not `<<<` which is meant for here-strings, a bourne again shell specific feature.

Answer (score 3):

It does that because `sh-electric-here-document-mode` is enabled.  To disable it interactively, just do <kbd>M-x</kbd> `sh-electric-here-document-mode`.

In Emacs 24 this minor mode was enabled by `sh-mode` by default, but you could use `sh-mode-hook` to disable it again.

In Emacs 25 `sh-mode-hook` includes `sh-electric-here-document-mode` by default (rather than `sh-mode` invoking it directly), so you can remove it via:
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `sh-mode-hook` <kbd>RET</kbd>